# What stops a website owner from putting cost per view ads in a hidden div?

Tags: advertising, website-design

I just started a website and want to put some ads on it to make it pay for itself. Given that nobody ever clicks on those, I thought that CPC (cost-per-click) is not an option and decided to go with CPM/CPV ads. Here's my question. What exactly stops me from putting hundred of those on each page of my web site and wrapping them into something like

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">ad banner</div>
```

The impressions/views would still be counted, right? Or am I not understanding something.

Comment: If I were paying you to advertise, I'd certainly be checking your site to make sure I was getting my money's worth. If I saw "hidden" in the source, you would be hearing from my lawyers.

Comment: I don't know if large ads networks would be bothering checking every site that uses their third-party services to properly display ads. Ads that don't even belong to them. I mean, look at the stats of this network. 10bn impressions per month https://adsterra.com/about-us/?lang=en

Comment: You would be seriously playing with someones money and causing the ad company their reputation and earning potential. Ad networks **ALL** check sites for proper placement. To do something like you are suggesting, you would be caught soon enough and is actually fraud in the eyes of the law. Don't think that the ad companies have not figured out how to cover their @$$e$ and do not seek legal recourse. In a business of small margins in the fractions of a penny, tight regulation of the business model is required or bankruptcy is inevitable. Policing ad policies becomes extremely paramount.

Comment: That is one of the reasons that almost all advertisements are CPC.   When users have to click on the ads, the site the ads are on has far less incentive to do shady things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside the legitimacy and legality of what you suggest, ad serving is more intelligent these days than it was even just a few years ago. These days most ad networks use crawlers to identify the content on your site and better target ads to the end users based on the subject matter of your site. In doing this most of these crawlers also check to see placement of ads, competing ads, visibility of ads, etc. With this sort of check they can also see if javascript or CSS is being used to either make the block invisible to the end user or positioning it under other content or off the page. When this sort of coding is detected the ad networks have all sorts of methods at their disposal to deal with it, with most if not all simply deactivating ad serving on your site, and depending on the nature of the ad serving agreement and the country you are in and the site is targeted to they may even take legal action to recoup any money they have already paid to you under fraud laws. Basically there is no way to do this without being caught and the penalties if when caught can be very high.

Comment: Fair enough. I think this is what I wanted to hear.